# Fix MS Excel cells to text permenantly

Tags: excel

I have a column which contains productIDs which are similar to numbers

```
ProductIDS
46257547467
65464564656
47682542896
68683582757
```

I also converted it to text using `=TEXT(cellNO,"0")` and it works fine for that time. But next time after few hours when I open the file it reads that column as numbers like this:

```
ProductIDS
4.62E+10
6.54E+10
4.76E+10
6.86E+10
```

How can I permanently convert it to text so that when I open it every time it shows me the column as text ? Thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Does the `=TEXT(cellNO,"0")` formula disappear? Or is the formula there, but it still displays the number in scientific format? What version of Excel? More information is needed here.

Comment: After applying the formula, I paste all the cells as values. So now formula is no more here but the values are converted into text. But next time I open the file it again shows those values in scientific format.

Comment: Why not just apply 'Text' formatting to the cells?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're attempting to generate unique IDs within an Excel sheet (for use in another application, maybe...?). Using a formula here won't do much good if a) new rows are being added (particularly intermingled with existing rows), or b) the formula is based on the context of the sheet.

I've written a little sub that generates a unique ID for a given column, auto-populating it when something about that row gets populated. It works for a range of inserted rows too, not just the current row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal targetRange As Range)
    ' Confirm that the change is occuring where I want to track it
    If targetRange.Column = Range("WhereChangeOccurs").Column Then
        ' Capture the target column holding the IDs
        Dim IDRangeColumn As Integer
        IDRangeColumn = Range("IDRange").Column

        ' Loop through each row of the target range, inserting an ID literal
        For Each thisrow In targetRange.Rows
            ' update the ID with
            '   DateTime (to milliseconds) plus
            '   unique GUID based on system
            Cells(thisrow.Row, IDRangeColumn).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd: hh.mm.ssss-") & Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 18)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

It's pretty fast, and the uniqueness holds up even when inserting multiple rows (so far checked to about 50-100 rows at a time). This has the benefit of *always* generating a unique ID for a row, without needing Copy-Paste-Values; no human intervention required.

Note that the ", 18)" in the ID generation can be a longer number if you'd rather use that for uniqueness; I wanted something readable (date/time) at the beginning simply for human understandability.